# Can sea wave make ions?

Tags: waves, charge, ions

I came into this [website](http://www.allwayswell.com/blog/ionization-of-waves-near-the-beach) and thought it is not true.
The i remembered you can ionize a rod by rubbing cloth so it might be possible.
No matter if these ions can be absorbed or have significant effect on body, im asking about the presence of ions because of wave.
So is it true?

Comment: [Link](https://www.nsf.gov/news/special_reports/water/index_low.jsp?id=ions).

Comment: "Charge" is a better word than "ionize" if you want to describe what rubbing objects with cloth can do.

Answer (score 1):

The sea does not have to make ions - it already contains a significant concentration of sodium ions (10 g/L) and chloride ions (20 g/L), along with smaller concentrations of other ions such as sulfate, magnesium, calcium, potassium and bi-carbonate (https://www.lenntech.com/composition-seawater.htm). These have been dissolved from the rocks over which river water has flowed before reaching the sea, and from rocks at the shore which have been pounded by waves (https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/whysalty.html).

All that is needed is for these ions to be thrown into the air - which happens when spray is created by wave action.

It is not necessary for water to be "rubbed" to separate these charges.